# Django 3.x error: 'mysql.connector.django' isn't an available database backend

Tags: python, mysql, django, mysql-connector-python

Having recently upgraded a Django project from 2.x to 3.x, I noticed that the `mysql.connector.django` backend (from `mysql-connector-python`) no longer works. The last version of Django that it works with is 2.2.11. It breaks with 3.0. I am using `mysql-connector-python==8.0.19`.

When running `manage.py runserver`, the following error occurs:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'mysql.connector.django' isn't an available database backend.
Try using 'django.db.backends.XXX', where XXX is one of:
    'mysql', 'oracle', 'postgresql', 'sqlite3'
```

I am aware that this is not an official Django backend but I have to use it on this project for reasons beyond my control.

I am 80% sure this is an issue with the library but I'm just looking to see if there is anything that can be done to resolve it beyond waiting for an update.

UPDATE:

`mysql.connector.django` now works with Django 3+.

Comment: which version of python are you using?

Comment: I am using Python 3.7.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For `Django 3.0` and `Django 3.1` I managed to have it working with `mysql-connector-python 8.0.22`. See this https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/connector-python/en/news-8-0-22.html.

Comment: I tried the latest version a while ago and it imports from `django.db.backends.mysql.base`, which requires `mysqlclient`. The old version of `mysql-connector-python` didn't. I can't use `mysqlclient` in this one particular project. Please correct me if wrong.

Comment: There is no `mysqlclient` in the pipfile of the project I was  working on.

Comment: In my case when I tried Django 3.2 and `mysql-connector-python` 8.0.25 it complained that I didn't have `mysqlclient` installed. It looks like the `mysqlclient` requirement was added after 8.0.22 in this commit when they now import `django.db.backends.mysql.base`: https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-python/commit/407ac56ad770322d43acafc5c18622b79bc63d96#diff-021c9eb7e40afc07c92a0503ab973f4b5d9ad34310cd3021ed926d7da0a9e027

Comment: Using `Django 3.1` is not an option?

Comment: I guess so, just not ideal that support drops off after that. Anyway, I'll update the accepted answer seeing as yours is now most relevant.

Answer (score 2):

Connector/Python still supports Python 2.7, which was dropped by Django 3.
We are currently working on adding support for Django 3, stay tunned.

Comment: Is there any place that this can be tracked? I filed a bug report a while ago but it has not been acknowledged yet: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=99106

Comment: Yes. There's a contribution that we are working on. See https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=99069
This bug will also be updated.

Comment: These bug reports seem to have gone pretty quiet.

Comment: @alstr they will be updated once the work is released. Which will be soon.

Comment: `mysql.connector.django` now works with Django 3+, however, it also now requires that you use `mysqlclient` as it imports from `django.db.backends.mysql.base` as opposed to `django.db.backends.base.base` as previously. In one project I cannot use `mysqlclient` (my reason for using the connector in the first place), so this problem remains.

Comment: Correct. But that was fixed in 8.0.26, it doesn't have the dependency anymore (Bug #32947160).  See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/connector-python/en/news-8-0-26.html

Comment: I'm not able to test this at the moment but it is good to know for future!

Comment: Confirming that 8.0.26-8.029 work as expected, however >= 8.0.30 I get database errors when running locally (weirdly, it works on the live server).

Answer (score -2):

in settings.py change database engine this way
'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql'